# Andoid BLE createBond returns false on some devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Integrating with a BLE glucometer.  Pretty straightforward.  I'm following the BLE Spec.

Phone is a Motorola G32...will.  On various occasions I will get a createBond() call that returns false?

It's very random.  I'm trying to track it down with little success and looking for some guidance on what might trigger this to happen?

createBond() is an async call so it returns immediately and then I have a BroadcastReceiver listening for BT events.

here's some relevant code if anyone has any insight whatsoever.

```
            boolean tryToBond = getDevice().createBond();

        if (!tryToBond) {
            if (connectCtx != null) {
                connectCtx.error(getPluginResponseObject(failedToCreateBond, "Failed to initiate pairing.  createBond() return false")); // "Failed to initiate pairing.  createBond() return false");
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Also here is the receiver.  Both are very simple...I'm leaning towards it being something simple and unrelated to the code but I can't figure out what.

Receiver code:

```
if (getDevice().getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) { // YOU CAN IGNORE THIS LINE JUST SHOWING THAT WE ONLY REGISTER AND CALL CREATEBOND IF IT'S NOT ALREADY BONDED
        pairingBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    aDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (aDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        //means device paired
                        Log.d("bt", "bonded");
                        pairingState = pairingStateEnum.success;
                    }
                    if (aDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE){
                        Log.d("bt", "bonding failed");
                        pairingState = pairingStateEnum.failure;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: So are you starting a bonding process from both your transmitter and receiver? If that is the case then it is possible that you are hitting a race condition because the AndroidOS might already be trying to do the bonding for you. Have a look at these links for the pecularities of the createBond() method: https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-4-72a0b85cb442 and https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  createBond() is being called from my Android source code.  The peripheral is a Glucometer that has an explicit "Pairing" button that puts it into a pairing mode.

Those two links you placed above are quite detailed and thorough.  Thank you for posting those